# Python "object" class. Is it just blank or there is something more about it?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm trying to find some more information about the Python base class: `object` but can't find any. Is it just something like `class object: pass` and doesn't deserve any more attention or...?

Where can I find more about it. What do other classes inherit from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some good info [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/03/the-fundamental-types-of-python-a-diagram/) (and in other articles linked from there). Here's the diagram:

[image]

Comment: I think the diagram here(at the bottom) is better: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html

Comment: @jamylak: I like that article, but the diagram is incomplete since it doesn't address custom metaclasses, which IMO are important. Also I find the visual distinction between "inherit" and "type" lines not clear enough

Answer (score 2):

Some basic stuff for other objects to use.

```
>>> dir(object())
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', 
'__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

For more info of what these methods are for check http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html, and here's how they are implemented http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3d4d52e47431/Objects/object.c.